# Focussing a textarea using <textarea_id>.focus() method not working in ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Hi I am trying to focus on a `textarea`, when a button is clicked. With the help of `autofocus`, it focuses the `textarea` when the button is clicked for the 1st time to make that `textarea` visible. But, after that, all the subsequent clicks to the button fail to focus the `textarea` in ionic2.

Code used:

```
let elem = document.getElementById("text_input"); -- where text_input is the id of the text area
elem.focus();-- but it fails to focus the textarea
```

Html :

```
<ion-item>
  <h2 [hidden]="isEnabled"> {{ comment_text }} </h2>
  <button ion-button clear [hidden]="isEnabled (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
  <ion-row [hidden]="isShown">
    <textarea #input [(ngModel)]="comment_text" 
   id="commentsText" color="black" autofocus></textarea>
    <button ion-button icon-only clear id="done" (click)="done()">
      <ion-icon name="send" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

Typescript :

```
edit()
{
  this.isShown = false;
  this.isEnabled = true;
  let elem = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("commentsText");
  elem.focus();
}

done()
{
  this.isShown = true;
  this.isEnabled = false;
}
```

CSS:

```
 #commentsText{
   width:90%;
 }
 #done{
   margin-right:5px;
 }
```

Comment: `let elem = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("text_input"); elem.focus();`. This works perfectly for me. Can you check if it is a typecasting problem? Also, can you check your console output on, what happens when you click the button and it does not work.

Comment: Tried but not working... Also console doesn't show any output on button click..  Basically my textarea is hidden, when i click on the button the textarea is shown and should have focus... But the focussing of the textarea is not working..

Comment: Could you provide a little more code for this. Like UI and typescript part? Also, may be css. Can't help without looking at the code. :)

Comment: Please edit your question with the code. And provide all the necessary code than only this part. Like from <textarea>...</textarea>. And, typescript code with the entire method you are doing it in.

Comment: If i dont hide the textarea then focussing is working fine but using hidden directive, it causes problem

Comment: Solved my issue by using setTimeout() function...